# Trace zero of a product of non square matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

**Question**:
Prove that if $S\in M_{n*m}\Bbb F, T\in M_{m*n}\Bbb F$ and $tr(ST)=0 \Rightarrow S=0,T=0$

**Things I did**
I read alot of questions here and figured that the matrices commute if their trace is zero, but this can only be true for square matrices.

Comment: The claim of the question is wrong, and so is the thing you "figured".

Comment: is that also false when tr(ST)=tr(TS)=0?

Comment: let both S and T be 1x1 matrices and S=[ 1 ] and T=[ 0 ] then tr(ST)=0 but S is non-zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S = I$ and

$$T = \begin{bmatrix} & & & 1 \\ & & 1 \\ & \dots \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Then $ST = TS = T$, which has a zero trace whenever the order of these matrices is even. However, $T$ and $S$ are obviously non-zero (they're not even singular!).

Being square or explicitly not square doesn't change a thing. Simply add zero rows and columns, and you'll get the same thing (you'll lose non-singularity, of course, but this is not the question here).

One could easily find many more examples, including square matrices of odd order.

As for your question from the comments, $\operatorname{tr} AB = \operatorname{tr} BA$ whenever both of these products are defined (check [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28linear_algebra%29#Basic_properties)).